# Why did Prophet married Aysha at the age of 6 when Quran forbids marriage before reaching puberty?

Tags: quran, hadith, nikah, prophet-muhammad, wife

According to many hadiths, Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) married Aysha (rali) at the age of 6 and consummated her at the age of 9 after reaching puberty. But according to the rules and laws of the Quran, one is allowed to marry only if he/she reached puberty.

Even if the marriage of the prophet and Aysha happened before the revelation of the ruling. We do also do know that Allah protected him at various circumstances when he was made by his relatives to do tawaf (shirk). Why can't Allah refrain him from marrying her at the age of 6 if it will be against the rulings of the Quran?

Because this is one of the most controversial and debated topics in Islam and I believe this has created only controversies among Muslims as to what her real age was during the marriage.

Or am I wrong in what I said? Please explain it clearly.

Comment: If you're asking about an apparent contradiction between the prophet's actions and a clear Qur'anic ruling, I would recommend referencing the actual ayah in question.

Comment: The Quran does not forbid contracting marriage before reaching puberty. [65:4](https://quran.com/65/4) talks about iddah of those who have not menstruated.

Comment: @goldPseudo I believe Quran 4: 6 speaks about it.

Comment: @UmH So, Are you saying that the nikah of Muhammad (pbuh) with Aysha (rali) at the age of 6 does not contradict any of the verses and laws in the Quran?

Comment: @MohmedShahid Yes. The Prophet later also arranged the nikah of the daughter of Hamza with ibn Abi Salama while both were minors, and the same was done by some of the Sahaba after him. There is general consensus among the jurists that marriage of a minor can be arranged by their guardian, all these people would not have agreed on something that contradicts the the Quran.

Comment: As for 4:6 it doesn't really forbid marriage before puberty, it is talking about when to release the property of orphans which is on having reached the age of consummation of marriage (i.e. puberty or ability to have intercourse) rather than the contract.

Answer (score -1):

She was not a child at the time of her marriage despite many assumptions.
In the booklet Prophet of Islam, which was later incorporated in 1948 as the first chapter of his book Living Thoughts of the Prophet Muhammad, Maulana Muhammad Ali writes in a lengthy footnote as follows:

“A great misconception prevails as to the age at which Aisha was taken in marriage by the Prophet. Ibn Sa‘d has stated in the Tabaqat that when Abu Bakr [father of Aisha] was approached on behalf of the Holy Prophet, he replied that the girl had already been betrothed to Jubair, and that he would have to settle the matter first with him. This shows that Aisha must have been approaching majority at the time. Again, the Isaba, speaking of the Prophet’s daughter Fatima, says that she was born five years before the Call and was about five years older than Aisha. This shows that Aisha must have been about ten years at the time of her betrothal to the Prophet, and not six years as she is generally supposed to be. This is further borne out by the fact that Aisha herself is reported to have stated that when the chapter [of the Holy Quran] entitled The Moon, the fifty-fourth chapter, was revealed, she was a girl playing about and remembered certain verses then revealed. Now the fifty-fourth chapter was undoubtedly revealed before the sixth year of the Call. All these considerations point to but one conclusion, viz., that Aisha could not have been less than ten years of age at the time of her nikah, which was virtually only a betrothal. And there is one report in the Tabaqat that Aisha was nine years of age at the time of nikah. Again it is a fact admitted on all hands that the nikah of Aisha took place in the tenth year of the Call in the month of Shawwal, while there is also preponderance of evidence as to the consummation of her marriage taking place in the second year of Hijra in the same month, which shows that full five years had elapsed between the nikah and the consummation. Hence there is not the least doubt that Aisha was at least nine or ten years of age at the time of betrothal, and **fourteen or fifteen years at the time of marriage**.”

To facilitate understanding dates of these events, please note that it was in the tenth year of the Call, i.e. the tenth year after the Holy Prophet Muhammad received his calling from God to his mission of prophethood, that his wife Khadija passed away, and the approach was made to Abu Bakr for the hand of his daughter Aisha. The hijra or emigration of the Holy Prophet to Madina took place three years later, and Aisha came to the household of the Holy Prophet in the second year after hijra. So if Aisha was born in the year of the Call, she would be ten years old at the time of the nikah and fifteen years old at the time of the consummation of the marriage.

For details, please see the following link, by Dr. Zakir Naik
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eT-Rh1auG0A

Answer (score -1):

Qur'an and Hadith do not prohibit from marrying at any age. In addition, you can refer to some of the links to understand

Source [Age of Aisha](https://yaqeeninstitute.org/faraz-malik/the-age-of-aisha-ra-rejecting-historical-revisionism-and-modernist-presumptions/)
More on [Ending Debate on Aisha's Age](https://yaqeeninstitute.org/omar-suleiman/ending-the-debate-on-aisha-ras-age-sh-omar-suleiman-lecture/);
[Clip on Aisha's Age](https://yaqeeninstitute.org/nuriddeen-knight/the-woman-behind-the-number-the-irrelevance-of-the-age-of-aisha-behind-the-scenes/) &
[Infographic on Aisha's Age](https://yaqeeninstitute.org/nuriddeen-knight/was-the-age-of-aisha-always-problematic-inforgraphic/)